# Change Microsoft Edge WebView2 user agent

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have Microsoft outlook desktop version (Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2209 Build 16.0.15629.20256) 64-bit) installed on a Windows 10 PC and I'm trying to add an office 365 account there. The problem comes, that the organization's SSO filters access requests based on user agent (verified through my own testing). So, if it detects Windows or Mac, it tells you to go away. Outlook uses Microsoft Edge WebView2 to open up the webpage for signing in. Is there a way I can change the user agent or force it to open a real browser for that sign-in?

Comment: Can the WebView2 user agent be changed if it was your own application, yes, but not outlook’s user agent because you don’t have that type of control over the application

Comment: The only way I can think of is replacing the .exe of the WebView2 with one that just calls the original with a hardcoded user agent. But I haven't tested it yet and I'm not sure if I want to go that route

Answer (score -1):

If you want to outlook open the default browser when you login?

If so, you could check if the default browser has configured in your computer? Following the guidance to [Change The Default Browser In Outlook](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1509-outlook-change-default-browser.html)

Additional information: [How To Change User Agent in Microsoft Edge](https://winaero.com/change-user-agent-microsoft-edge/#:%7E:text=1%20Open%20Microsoft%20Edge.%202%20Press%20the%20F12,web%20browser%20to%20change%20the%20user%20agent%20string.)